# How can I detect a Touch on an image?

Tags: ios, touchesbegan

This is really basic stuff, but I can't seem to get it right (I'm new to programming). What I'm trying to do is, have my Xcode 5 App detect if an image with a certain name (say for ex. @"go.png" is pressed or touched. How can I do this? There are only two buttons, so I've been doing it with the (touchLocation.y and .x ...) method, but I need to have the Button being pressed method now. I have pasted the code below. I really appreciate your help everyone.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];


switch (_flyGo) {
    case HeadMenu:
        if (touchLocation.y < self.size.height * 0.7) {
        } else if (touchLocation.x < self.size.width * 0.3) {
            [self switchNewFly:FlyTutorial];
        } else {
            [self giveRatingToApp];
        }
        break;
    case FlyTutorial:
        [self switchToFly];
        break;
    case FlyStatePlay:
        [self flyPlayer];
        break;
    case FlyDisplayFalling:
        break;
    case FlyDisplayScore:
        break;
    case FlyDisplayDone:
        if (touchLocation.x < self.size.width * 0.6) {
            [self switchNewFly:FlyDisplayTutorial]; 
        } else {
            [self ShareMyScore];
        }
        break;
}




//I would like to get an image for ex. "flyer.png" to be detected as a touch instead of using (touchLocation.x or .y < self.size.width * 0.6)
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: If it's a button, why don't you add selector to your button to do what you want on button touch?

Comment: Are you trying to detect the button image? I mean the image you have set for the button?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can

Add touch recogniser to UIImageView (don't forget to set     imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
). Also set tag property for imgView to some value.

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapAll:)];
 tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
 tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
 [imgView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Then

```
- (void)handleTapAll:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;
    if(img.tag == some_vale) //your code


}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
......

ViewController.m
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"];

imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
imageView.exclusiveTouch = YES;
imageView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;


// Add tap gesture
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
tap.delegate = self;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];


- (IBAction)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer { //Your code here }
```